# Como posso inserir um novo dado em um banco de dados do SQL?

Tags: sql

Iniciei hoje um curso de SQL server e como trabalho autônomo o professor nos deu atividade:
inserir um novo curso chamado 'Inteligencia Artificial' com a sigla 'IA'
Tenho duvidas sobre qual comando e como utilizar
seria algo parecido com
alter table db.cursos add collum Nome 'Inteligencia Artificial', sigla 'IA'?

Desde já agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Você irá utilizar o comando `insert` para entender melhor veja este [exemplo](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Usa-se o comando `INSERT INTO` para isso.

Esse comando, de maneira bem resumida, é assim (tanto faz maiúsculas ou minúsculas no comando):

```
INSERT INTO tabela (campos) VALUES (valores);
```

Detalhando um pouco mais,

```
INSERT INTO nome_da_tabela (campo1, campo2, campo3) VALUES (valor1, valor2, valor3);
```

Vai ser sempre esse formato, com variações.

Por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO cursos (nome, sigla, codigo) VALUES ('Inteligência Artificial', 'IA', 42);
```

Deve-se atentar para inserir nos campos o mesmo tipo de dado que foi declarado na criação da tabela. Por exemplo 12 se for um campo numérico, "ABC" se for um campo de texto, etc.

Um detalhe a mais:

A SQL aceita caracteres especiais nos identificadores (isto é, nos nomes das colunas e das tabelas), bem como o uso de palavras consideradas reservadas pela linguagem, o que pode causar alguma confusão. Dependendo do nome que foi usado, isso pode causar problemas na hora de tentar emitir o comando. Nesse caso envolva o identificador problemático com caracteres de acento grave (aqueles das crases), por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO `nome_da_tabela` (`campo1`, ...
```

Por fim, vale lembrar que `INSERT INTO` faz parte da DML, isto é, do conjunto de comandos de "manipulação" de dados da SQL (juntamente com `DELETE FROM`, `UPDATE` e `SELECT`).

Já o `ALTER TABLE` faz parte da DDL ou comandos de "definição" de dados (no caso, de tabelas, juntamente com `CREATE TABLE` e `DROP TABLE`).

Comment: Obrigada a todos pela ajuda. Consegui solucionar utilizando o exemplo do insert to

Comment: Que bom. Não se esqueça de "aceitar" a resposta que lhe atendeu, clicando no "v" verde do lado esquerdo da resposta.